# In Vim (with YouCompleteMe), can I limit the number of possible completions shown?

Tags: vim

I am using [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) for identifier completion in Vim. I would like to limit the size of the completion popup so that it is never more than 5 entries. Can this be done?

Comment: What does the plugin's documentation say on that matter?

Comment: @romainl That linked page is the documentation; as far as I can tell it is silent on the matter.

Comment: So you already have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'pumheight'` option sets the maximum height of the menu. It doesn't restrict the number of suggestions, though. Only the script responsible for gathering those suggestions and feeding them into the completion menu can decide how many suggestions to display.

If YCM doesn't do that, send the author a formal feature request.